# Can i use bind method of Connection with newAuthenticatedConnectionFactory in OpenDJ?

Tags: opendj

I have created a class to provide connection pooling with OpenDJ. Now i am trying to authenticate a user using another class which picks a connection from the pool.

If I use newAuthenticatedConnectionFactory method to create the pool then it gives UnsupportedOperation exception while it works fine if I use newFixedConnectionPool.

Why is it so? Is bind method not allowed with newAuthenticatedConnectionFactory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An authenticatedConnectionFactory is a method to obtain a connection on which a well known user is already authenticated. Therefore it's not suited to do other authentication and Bind request.